# Where in the redux lifecycle I should call methods to show notifications (toasts)?

Tags: angular, toast, ngrx

I am building angular2 app with ngrx/store. Where in the redux lifecycle I should call methods to show notifications (toasts)?

My current guess is that I should do it in side effects (I use ngrx/effects).

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false }) public newBidPublished$: any = this._actions$
    .ofType(BiddingStatusActions.NEW_BID_PUBLISHED)
    .map((action) => action.payload)
    .map((biddingStatus: GetBiddingStatusApiResponseModel) => {
        let msg = '<p>New bid has arrived.</p>';

        // PROBLEM HERE: I don't have access to previous bidding status here:
        if (biddingStatus.tenderRank !== 1 && previousBiddingStatus.tenderRank === 1) {
            msg += '<p>You are no longer in leading position.</p>';
        }

        this._notificationsService.info(msg);
    });
```

However there is one big problem: I need to access previous state to be able to compare if current bid has lost leading position. The only place where I am able to access both current and previous state is reducer. But I doubt it is a good place to show notifications and as it is not a service, I cannot inject NotificationService there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an example from my own application. The main point is to use the `selector` which will select for you the current state before you modify it (before the moving new data from Effect to Reducer).

```
@Effect()
logout$: Observable<RouterActions.All | AccountActions.All> = this.actions$
.ofType<AccountActions.Logout>(AccountActions.LOGOUT)
.pipe(
  exhaustMap(() => this.API.auth.revokeToken()),
  // We are using selector to get a slice of the state
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromAccount.selectUser)),
  // The operator above returns an array and we select the second item
  // which is our user/your state.
  map(([, user]) => user),
  map((user: User) => this.redirectUser(user))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the Store into the Effects class and have access to it from there.

```
constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<State>,
) { }

private state$ = this.store.withLatestFrom(state => state).take(1);
```

Now you have the whole state in an Observable, that you can pass to other Observables with `switchMap` or combine using other operators.

Of course you should only select the slice of state that interests you, not the whole state.

Comment: Tried it but still can't understand how to take the previous state. The state$ still returns latest state when subscribing to it. Tried "take(2)" but no use.

P.S. I am newbie in Rxjs.

Comment: If you need access to the previous state then you obviously need to save it in your reducer. You can check out `redo/undo redux` on Google for tips on how to save previous states. After having saved the previous state in the reducer you can simply access it using the way I described. By the way: the `take(1)` operator unsubscribes after `taking one element from the Observable`. Without it you would have a potential memory leak in your app.